# Why do we say Undisclosed or Non-Disclosure instead of Closed or Closure

Tags: expressions

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclosure), disclosure's etymology comes from Latin dis-+clausus, literally away+enclosed.

I wonder why do the term [closed](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sold+for+a+closed+amount%22) is not in common use as the term [undisclosed](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sold+for+an+undisclosed+amount%22).

*Not Not True* is simply *True*, and *Not Not False* is Simply *False* (`!!1==1`)

Comment: Yeah, right!!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Etymology is not the same thing as definition. *Disclosed* does not mean *not closed*. *Undisclosed* means “not made known or public”. *Closed* means “not open”.